# Is there a squarefree number between any two squares?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to prove that $\sqrt{x} \leq 2^{\pi(x)}$ for all $x \geq 0 \in \mathbb R$, where $\pi$ is the prime-counting function. To do this, I note that $2^{\pi(x)}$ may be viewed as the number of different products we may produce from the $\pi(x)$ different primes that are at most $x$; since in each such product the power of each prime is at most one, each product is squarefree. Since by convention 1 is squarefree, then $2^{\pi(x)}$ is precisely the number of squarefree numbers at most $x$.

Furthermore, $\lceil \sqrt{x}\rceil = \left|\{n^2 : n^2 \leq x\}\right|$ (with equality if and only if $x$ is a square), so that proving that $\sqrt{x} \leq 2^{\pi(x)}$ is equivalent to showing that there is an injection
$$f : \{n^2 \in \mathbb Z : n^2 \leq x\} \to \{n : n \leq x \text{ and $n$ is squarefree}\}.$$
Supposing that for any integer $n \geq 1$ there is some squarefree number $k$ such that $n^2 < k < (n + 1)^2$, then producing such an injective function is trivial. But I do not see a way to prove this last claim: that between any two squares there is a squarefree number. How does one prove this statement?

Comment: @DietrichBurde That's a stronger result than what I need, with a correspondingly more complicated proof. I'm primarily looking for a basic elementary proof of my claim.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think I'll have to find a different way to attack the problem, then. It's an introductory problem and it shouldn't require anything more than a simple proof.

Comment: If your task is to simply show that $\sqrt{x} \leqslant 2^{\pi(x)}$, you're overcomplicating it, and trying to prove far more than you need. Note that you can write every positive integer $n \leqslant x$ uniquely as $n = a\cdot b^2$ with a squarefree $a$. Then note that there are $\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor$ squares $\leqslant x$, and $\leqslant 2^{\pi(x)}$ squarefree numbers. So $\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor \cdot 2^{\pi(x)} \geqslant x$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think that's the proof that the problem is aimed at. It seems I certainly was overcomplicating things!